# How to make request to localhost form docker container?

Tags: python, docker, request, localhost, containers

I use docker-compose. I want to make request to localhost.
But I'm getting this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
   HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=9011): Max retries exceeded 
with url: /api/user/registration (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
   0x7fac61209110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] 
   Connection refused'))
```

My code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:9011')
print(response.content)
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: runserver
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - 'static:/opt/app/static:rw'
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

volumes:
  static:
```

Comment: You assigned a port to the docker container? showing your docker-compose.yml would be helpful.

Comment: is there anything running on `response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:9011')` port 9011? 
If you call localhost from inside a docker container you call the host inside of the docker container. You might want to use the docker host network

Comment: Yes, there is my site. But i cant to make request to this site.

Comment: The canonical IP address for localhost is `127.0.0.1`.  In Docker that almost always means "this container", so if your container isn't serving anything on port 9011, you're probably looking for a different host name or IP address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have find the answer. You should add `network_mode: host` to `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: runserver
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - 'static:/opt/app/static:rw'
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    network_mode: host  # Added this


volumes:
  static:
```

Comment: This is almost always a workaround to some deeper problem; it's like solving permission issues by running as root.

Comment: Yes! But for some testing purposes it's realy helpfull.